# reduxForm doesn't seem to be mapping state to props

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I just upgraded from `redux-form:5.3.2` to `6.0.5`. I've modified my sign in form and it looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import * as actions from '../actions/authActions';


class SignIn extends Component {

  handleFormSubmit({ email, password }) {
    console.log(this.props);
    this.props.signinUser({ email, password }, this.props.location);
  }

  renderAlert() {
    if (this.props.errorMessage) {
      return (
        <div className="alert alert-danger">
          {this.props.errorMessage}
        </div>
      );
    } else if (this.props.location.query.error) {
      return (
        <div className="alert alert-danger">
          Authorization required!
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

  render() {

    const { message, handleSubmit } = this.props;

    const renderField = ({input, label, type, meta: { touched, error } }) => (
      <fieldset className="form-group">
        <label>{label}</label>
        <input {...input} className="form-control" />
      </fieldset>
    )


    return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this))}>
        {this.renderAlert()}
        <Field name="username" type="text" component={renderField} label="Username"/>
        <Field name="password" type="password" component={renderField} label="Password"/>
        <button action="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Sign In</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { errorMessage: state.auth.error }
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'signin',
  fields: ['email', 'password']
}, mapStateToProps, actions)(SignIn)
```

Prior to the upgrade, I wasn't using the `Field` component but most eveything else is the same and my action `this.props.signinUser` was getting called. However, now it doesn't exist in `this.props`. Downgrading to `5.3.2` continues to work. I haven't gone through the process of gradually upgrading to find it out where it broke, if it is broke and assuming I didn't do something wrong.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And...I just found the answer. I had to change this:

```
export default reduxForm({
  form: 'signin',
  fields: ['email', 'password']
}, mapStateToProps, actions)(SignIn)
```

to this:

```
SignIn = reduxForm({
  form: 'signin',
  fields: ['email', 'password']
})(SignIn);

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(SignIn);
```

This doesn't appear to be in the docs, but it should be.

Comment: hm... interesting reduxForm doesn't connect to redux store for you?

Comment: It used to but not in the newer versions.